# Function of excel addin working on my computer but adding the path file in another computer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with excel addin. I wrote a code that is working fine in my computer. It's a function made by me and saved as an addin format.

When i send an excel file to my coworkers - everybody have the addin installed on their computers - the formulas in excel are changed - the file path of the addin in my computer is added to the formula of funciton.

This is very bad because we have a very large table using these formulas. If we replace the file path with string "" the function works because they have the addin installed.

This is an example:
In my computer the excel formula is:

```
BAIXAR($B8;D$7)
```

In my coworkers the excel formula is:

```
'C:\Users\Thomaz\Desktop\ADD IN BUSCA CONTAS FILTRO POR EMPRESA.xlam'!BAIXAR($B8;D$7)'C:\Users\Thomaz\Desktop\ADD IN BUSCA CONTAS FILTRO POR EMPRESA.xlam'!BAIXAR($B8;D$7)
```

I guess that the formula try to connect with my addin not with the addin that is the same that i have here that is already installed in their computers.

Really need your help.

Comment: Welcome Humberto Neto, if you share the code, we can check whether you could use `"thisworkbook.worksheets("worksheetname")...`
in your workbook, when you are creating a formula on your excelsheet within your macro. (In stead of letting excel automatically create the reference to it's own workbook, [for example when you make the code by modifiying a recording]).

Comment: hello! thanks for your help. 

the formula is in a cell in a sheet not inside my piece of code in vba. it's a very simple code that executes a search in some cells and return the value. the code is this:
Public Function BAIXAR(conta, periodo)


Dim auxiliar As String

auxiliar = conta
coluna = 0
linha = 0
coluna2 = 0
linha2 = 0
If auxiliar = "DEP" Then
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If Cells(249999, 992 + i) = periodo Then
            coluna2 = i + 992
            i = 2000
        End If
    Next i
    BAIXAR = Cells(1, coluna2)

Comment: @HumbertoNeto Please edit your question to show your code.  It is quite difficult to read when you post it in a comment, as you have.